# How to "wrap_content" the height of a horizontal ListView in a column using Flutter

Tags: flutter

Using Flutter, how can I dynamically assign the height of a horizontal ListView in a Column to take up exactly how much height is needed by the ListView items.

For example, the following snippet shows a Column with 2 main child widgets, a `ColoredBox` and a `ListView.Builder`. The `ListView.builder` is wrapped by a `SizedBox` that specifies its height to be exactly 40 while the `ColoredBox` is wrapped by `Expanded` allowing it to take up all the remaining height in the Column.

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          const Expanded(
            child: ColoredBox(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text('Expanded top widget'),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 5,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Text('Card $index'),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

This runs without error but requires the `ListView.builder` to be wrapped by the `SizedBox` to define an explicit height and if the `SizedBox` is removed, an unbounded height exception occurs.

I'm trying to allow the ListView to take up a dynamic amount of height based off its child elements but am having trouble getting it to work.

I've tried setting the ListView's `shrinkWrap` to true but that didn't help.

I've also verified that you can wrap both the ListView and the upper `Text` widgets in `Expanded` and assign them `flex` values to assign them heights based on percentages of the screen without error but that's still not what I'm trying to accomplish.

Is there a way to have the `ListView.builder` dynamically assign its height based off its child elements (the Cards in this case) without explicitly assigning its height in pixels or screen height percentage similar to setting a view's height to "wrap_content" in a native Android XML layout file?

Answer (score 0):

```
add all in a Container with a specified size
exemple

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

Container(
            width: size.width * 0.98,
            height: size.height * 0.98,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: your Column,
          ),
```

if it work arrow up have a nice day

Comment: ListView will change size automatically depending of the child,